# Text created by innerHTML does not shrink responsively

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

The elements created by innerHTML do not shrink with other elements within the flex container.

My goal is to make it shrink together with the .titleBar.

.nums seems to exceed its container #display even though flex-wrap: wrap; and flex-basis: 0; is set.

```js
score.innerHTML = `${p1score.toString().padStart(2, "0")} - ${p2score.toString().padStart(2, "0")}`;
stopWatch.innerHTML = hr.toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":" + min.toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":" + sec.toString().padStart(2, "0");
```

```css
#display {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  justify-self: center;
  padding: 0px;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-shrink: 10;
}

.titlebar {
  font-size: 5vh;
  font-weight: 550;
  margin: auto;
}

.nums {
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-family: Oswald;
  margin-top: auto;
}

#score {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="display">
  <p class="titlebar" id="topTitle"> ROUND TIME</p>
  <p id="time" class="nums">00:00:00</p>
  <button id="start" class="ctrlBtn">START</button>
  <p id="scoreLabel" class="titlebar"> PLAYER SCORES </p>
  <p id="score" class="nums"> 00 - 00</p>
</section>
```

Stretched:
[image: stretched]

Shrinked:
[image: shrinked]

Comment: Please provide enough JavaScript for the snippet to function correctly

Comment: If its only text content, use `element.textContent` instead of `element.innerHTML` so that you don't inadvertently inject html, helping prevent some XXS bugs.

Comment: @AllanJ. What are the instances where element.innerHTML is useful?

Comment: @SkyCowie it is useful when you have **Sanitized** html that needs to be rendered. It is preferable to use `Document.createElement()` and related apis when possible, as you can insert html content with low to no XSS risk. Sanitizing HTML is no easy feat, as you can trigger javascript with more than just script tags.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `flex-basis`, `flex-grow`, or `flex-shrink` on the flex container (`.display`) they are assigned to the flex container's direct descendants (child elements). Moreover, it's recommended that you use the shorthand property `flex` instead. I personally avoid those properties because I use other means to gain responsiveness.

Default `font-size` is set on `<html>` which means any text that doesn't have an explicit or inherited `font-size` will have the default `font-size`.

Try setting default `font-size` in `vmax` units. `vmax` units alternate between `vh` and `vw` units -- which of the two that it is at any given time is dependent upon which length of the viewport is bigger. If the viewport is wider (most likely on desktops, laptops, etc) then `vmax` is `vw` and if the viewport is taller (mobile portrait mode) then `vmax` is `vh`. So if there are any changes to the viewport, the default `font-size` changes. Although the default `font-size` will shrink and grow some text, there are elements that set a default `font-size` of their own (like `h1-h6`) -- so you could have bigger text in a `<p>` than in a `<h4>`.

To avoid lopsided scaling, use `rem` for everything except small lengths like border width. `rem` units are directly proportional to the default `font-size`. So, if you have...

**Figure I**

```
html {
  font: 3vmax/1.5 Oswald
}
```

...each `rem` would equal `3vh` or `3vw`. See if this technique facilitates responsiveness by reviewing the example below. Review in full page mode, not in the iframe window and use dev tools to shrink it (see **Figure II**)

**Figure II**

[image]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300&family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap');

html {
  font: 3vmax/1.5 Oswald
}

.display * {
  display: block;
}

.display {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  justify-self: center;
  padding: 0px;
}

.titlebar {
  margin: auto;
  font: 500 3rem/1.5 Raleway;
  text-align: center;
}

.number {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: Consolas;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 2rem;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="display">
  <h1 class="titlebar">ROUND TIME</h1>
  <time class="time number">00:00:00</time>
  <button class="start">START</button>
  <h2 class="titlebar">PLAYER SCORES </h2>
  <output class="score number">00 - 00</output>
</section>
```